# Search through array in json file using filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm having trouble using `.filter`, to search through an array i have, which stores product data. I am able to pass the query term i want to the search page i have but can't seem to return the results.

This is my code and `Search results for {query}` shows the query entered as expected.

Having `.filter(results => results.match(new RegExp(query, "i")))` gives the error `results.match` is not a function.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { productData } from '../ProductData';

export const Search = () => {
  const location = useLocation();  
  const query = location.state;

  return (
    <div>
      Search results for {query}
        <ul>
          {productData
            .filter(results => JSON.stringify(results).match(new RegExp(query, "i")))
            .map(results => {
              return <li key={results.id}>{results.title} </li>
            })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is an example of the product data in my array

```
export const productData = [
    {   
        id:"1",
        title: "Echo (4th generation) | With premium sound, smart home hub and Alexa | Charcoal",
        price: 89.99,
        image: require("./Assets/Product Images/echo.png"),
        images: 
        [
            {
                src: require("./Assets/Product Images/echo.png"),
                title: "Amazon Echo"
            },
        ],
        monthly: 18.00,
        cat: "Smart Speaker",
        desc: "Premium sound—Echo delivers clear highs, dynamic mids and deep bass for rich, detailed sound that automatically adapts to any room. Voice control your entertainment—stream songs from Amazon Music, Apple Music, Spotify, Deezer and more. Plus listen to radio stations, podcasts and Audible audiobooks. Supports lossless HD audio available on select streaming services such as Amazon Music HD. Ready to help—ask Alexa to play music, answer questions, play the news, check the weather, set alarms, control compatible smart home devices and more.",
        details: 
        [
            {
                title: "Smart home made simple",
                para: "With the built-in hub, easily set up compatible Zigbee devices to voice control lights, locks and sensors. Fill your home with sound—with multi-room music, playing synchronised music across Echo devices in different rooms. You can also pair your Echo with Fire TV to feel scenes come to life with home cinema audio. Connect with others—call almost anyone hands free. Instantly drop in on other rooms or announce to the entire household that dinner's ready. Designed to protect your privacy—built with multiple layers of privacy protection and control, including a Microphone Off button that electronically disconnects the microphones."
            },
            {
                title: "Smart home made simple",
                para: "With the built-in hub, easily set up compatible Zigbee devices to voice control lights, locks and sensors. Fill your home with sound—with multi-room music, playing synchronised music across Echo devices in different rooms. You can also pair your Echo with Fire TV to feel scenes come to life with home cinema audio. Connect with others—call almost anyone hands free. Instantly drop in on other rooms or announce to the entire household that dinner's ready. Designed to protect your privacy—built with multiple layers of privacy protection and control, including a Microphone Off button that electronically disconnects the microphones."
            },
            {
                title: "Smart home made simple",
                para: "With the built-in hub, easily set up compatible Zigbee devices to voice control lights, locks and sensors. Fill your home with sound—with multi-room music, playing synchronised music across Echo devices in different rooms. You can also pair your Echo with Fire TV to feel scenes come to life with home cinema audio. Connect with others—call almost anyone hands free. Instantly drop in on other rooms or announce to the entire household that dinner's ready. Designed to protect your privacy—built with multiple layers of privacy protection and control, including a Microphone Off button that electronically disconnects the microphones."
            }

        ],
        brand: "Amazon",
        rating : 
        [
            {
            stars: 5,
            ratings: "11,048",
            }
        ],
    },
```

Comment: Wouldn't `results.toString()` produce `"[object Object]"` or do you have a custom `toString()` implementation? You probably want to use `JSON.stringify(results)`.

Comment: tried that still doesn't output the results

Comment: what is the value of query?

Comment: ```onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} ``` user input from the search bar

Comment: using @3limin4t0r comment i restarted my dev server and thats fixed it thank you.